# Need to disable Sticky Keys for every account on computer

Tags: windows, keyboard, key, settings, sticky

With a program that I'm working on, I have a need to be sure that keyboard access features like Sticky Keys is disabled for everyone.

I have code that can:

1. Change the active setting for the current user (enable or disable).  This only affects the current user when they are logged in and is not something that is permanently set.
2. Change the registry setting for the current user (disabling by setting HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys\Flags to "506").  This only affects the current user's registry entry and will make sure that the settings are set for each time they log into Windows.
3. Change the registry setting for the ".DEFAULT" user in a similar way as item 2.  This means that any ***new*** account that is set up on the computer will have Sticky Keys and the hot key for it disabled by default.

What I don't know how to do is to go about changing the setting for all of the ***existing*** users whose settings are in the registry when they are not logged in.  Essentially, I want to be sure that Sticky Keys are disabled for them.  Is there a convenient way that I can parse the registry for all existing user accounts and change that setting?

Comment: What if a user needs sticky keys?

Comment: For the particular environment that I have to develop for, having Sticky keys on or even having the risk of them being triggered is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I Understand Your Problem,  the answer is too long to post here,

Please Read this and it i think you will have your answer

let me know how you go

PS, The Link is safe and virus free, don't worry

[DISABLING STICKY KEYS FOR ALL USERS](http://blog.duklabs.com/?p=96)

One Last thing, i thought might be useful in your situation

Please be advised that, when you Access a Hidden File called "Default"  Under Users

C:\Users\Default

BE REALLY CAREFUL HERE (this file is critical)

Any Changes or settings made to this file will affect all users and all Future User Accounts

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I actually found that very page you referred to before asking this question and used its information in my attempt.  Unfortunately, changing the HKEY_USER/.DEFAULT's setting for the sticky keys does not change the setting for all existing users. Nor, does it seem to affect new users either (I create a new user after implementing my code only to see their flags set in the typical default).  The only user that I can seem to affect (in Windows 8.1, anyway) is the HKEY_CURRENT_USER's key.  I am hoping to find a solution to go beyond just that key.

Comment: Then, you must be doing something wrong, because that folder dictates the default setting for all newly created users. I've actually done this many times personally, I just found that page, so as to have something to give you as reference, this page is not where i got my experience from,  But the point is.. it definitely does work.

Comment: Even when I go to hand-edit HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Accessibility\StikeyKeys\Flags key value to "506" and then create a new user, the checkbox to enable the hot key for Sticky Keys is still checked in that new user's account (however, I am successful if I modify HKEY_CURRENT_USER).  Is there someplace else that I need to modify?

Comment: I'm going to sort of go backwards here a little (Perhaps this is a stupid question, but i'll ask anyway) Fundamentally, Sticky keys is a setting designed to be freindly to Disabled Users, Therefore (and sorry for asking)  did you check (All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Set up Sticky Keys) and Ensured that an Admin Account has "Turn on sticky keys when SHIFT is pressed five times" UNCHECKED.  I have tested this method and the last method and they both work, for newly created accounts.

Comment: some more food for thought, have you tried this Okay, go into
Control Panel
All Control Panel Items
Ease Of Access Settings
Change Administrative Settings
Select 'Apply All settings to the login desktop'
Click Apply.


Then, go back to ease of access center
Click on 'Make the keyboard easier to use'
Check 'turn on filter keys'
Uncheck 'turn on filter keys'
Click 'Apply' This method also worked for me, i have created a test environment to duplicate your issue and i seem to be having success whereas you don't seem to be having any luck, i'm wondering what the differences are ??